# Camel stream component with retry cause an endless loop

Tags: apache-camel

I am reading a file using the stream camel component. 
The behaviour I want is the following :

1. Read the stream
2. When the file roll over, start the reading the file from the begining

My code :

```
from("stream:file?fileName=myfile&scanStream=true&scanStreamDelay=1000&retry=true")
```

The problem with the code above is that the same file is read every 1000ms.
The component don't check is the file was rolled over.

Is there a solution with this component? Do I need to develop another route that will check if the file was rolled over?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: I'm using the version : 2.20.2

Comment: Ah okay I took a look, and yeah its a little bug. Camel does not have logic that checks that it should only retry when its a new/changed file. You are welcome to log a JIRA

Comment: Done, thank you :), the URL : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12551